# React Usestate to set state to false, i am using array having objects in it

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary, react-redux

**i want to change isAnswered to true whenever button op option is clicked please help i am stuck, i am loading options in buttons and when user clicks button, the state should update**

```
   const [Questions, setQuestios] = useState([
    {
        Question: "Random question",
        Options: [ {op1: "option", b:1 }, {op2: "option", b:2}, {op3: "option", b:3}],
        Akey: 1,
        key: 1,
        isAnswered: false
    },
    {
        Question: "Random question",
        Options: [ {op1: "option", b:1},  {op2: "option", b:2},  {op3: "option", b:3}],
        Akey: 1,
        key: 2,
        isAnswered: false
    }

const handlechange = (e) => {
    const bkey = e.target.attributes.getNamedItem('data-bbkey').value;
    if(bkey === e.target.value){
        console.log('hihii')
        setQuestios(prevState => ({ ...prevState, prevState.: true}));
    }else{
        console.log(e.currentTarget.innerText, bkey, e.currentTarget.value)
    }
}

return (
    <h1>{Questions.map(Question => (
        <div key={Math.random() *10}>{Question.Question}
        <div>
         {Question.Options.map(option => 
            <button data-bbkey={option.b} key={Math.random() *10} value={Question.Akey} onClick={e => handlechange(e)}>{option.op1}{option.op2}{option.op3}</button>
        )}
        </div>
        </div>
    ))}</h1>
)
```

Comment: Is the issue that when any single button is clicked that all the questions' `isAnswered` properties are set to true?

Comment: I want to set isAnswered property to true of that specific question whose button is clicked, pease help

Comment: Can you explain the `bKey === e.target.value` part, I'm not quite understanding that logic, the reason for it.

Comment: I have figured out the solution, i am passing a index in map function and onclick i will be passing that index to handlechange then getting object of that index from Questions array and setting isAnswered = true using useState, took me a while but i figured that, thanks for help :)

Comment: Yeah, that was going to be my suggestion but wasn't sure how to resolve it around the condition I asked about. Good on you, mate.